# Firefox reserves space for relatively positioned element even when it's placed elsewhere

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-position, scrollable

Use the following code in a firefox browser to reproduce the problem:

```html
<html>
  <body>
  <div class="bluediv" style="position: absolute;height: 400px;width: 400px;background-color: blue;">
    <div class="yellowdiv" style="height: 350px;width: 400px;background-color: yellow;">
    </div>
    <div class="reddiv" style="position: relative;top: -350px;left: 0;height: 100px;width: 100px;background-color: red;">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When the page is exactly as big as the bluediv (which is 400px), it is made scrollable, because the reddiv is taking up an extra 50px as it is in the bottom of the DOM. However, the reddiv is relatively positioned and actually takes space in the bottom left corner of the page. How can I get Firefox to not make the page scrollable above 400px?

My ideas:
- I can make the bluediv have no overflow visible, but I would not like to;
- I could make the red div have a fixed position, but it would also not be good.

Comment: This is entirely expected - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/IuLfJ

Comment: Thank you so much! Because Chrome doesn't do the same thing I was left thinking that it's a mistake. For Chrome this didn't make the page scrollable.